# Can't access/modify Firebase Billing Account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I've set up a firebase project not to long ago and linked it with a Google Cloud organization. I'm now trying to get the receipts for the monthly charges and I can't figure the hell out where to find them.

The Firebase Console lets me know that I'm not an "Billing Admin" for the associated project... but I also can't figure out who is
[image]

As per the image's suggestion, I went into the GCP console to find the billing account.
[image]

There seems to be one called "Firebase Payment" (after all I'm paying) but whenever I try to access/modify the account I'm presented with a message saying that I have no access. I tried with all users in my organization and **not a single one** has access.

Has anyone ever run into this problem before?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you create a Firebase project (with **Blaze** plan) and link it to an GCP org later you'll get the **Firebase Payment** billing account which can't be modified. To solve that problem for good, do the following

- Open the GCP dashboard and create a new billing account
- Once thats done, search for **Billing Accounts** and switch to the **My Projects** tab
  [image]
  Click **Change billing** and assign the newly creataed **Billing Account**

Answer (score 1):

Errors regarding "permissions" have to do with the role we have assigned in that particular project. If you have a role assigned in a particular protect, the access does not migrate to another project.  Each project has its own set of rules and they are controlled by the owner of the project.  Here is a list of the billing roles and what each role does:

> Billing account Administrator - The Billing Account Administrator role grants the IT department the permissions to associate projects with billing accounts, turn off billing for the projects, and view the credit card information for the accounts that they resell to their customers.
> It does not give them permissions to view the contents of the projects.

> Billing Account User -     The Billing Account User role gives the service account the permissions to enable billing (associate projects with the organization's billing account for all projects in the organization) and thereby permit the service account to enable APIs that require billing to be enabled.

> Billing Account Viewer -   The Billing Account Viewer role allows the developers to view the expenses for a billing account.

Here is a google document that provides a more detailed [explanation about the  different roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/billing#small_company_configuring_billing_permissions) for billing.

The owner of the project needs to provide you with the correct role in IAM in order for you to have [access](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org) to the information you are requesting.

You can also access a [billing report](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) using the following, but make sure you have the access `billing.accounts.getSpendingInformation`if you want such feature

Comment: Shouldn't the owner role be sufficient? I can't even assign "Billing Account Manager" the only thing simliar is "Project Billing Manager"

Comment: I had similar issues with a project, I have the owner role but for some reason I wasn't able to execute a change in a VPC.  I created a custom role and I added the right role with the help of the following list [1]

There are several owner roles

[1} https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic